# Exporting list of dictionaries to excel

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, dictionary

i have a list of dictionaries , trying to export it to excel .

```
P = {"@odata.context":"https://remedy.data/network","value"[{"CI_Name":"EB2CMA01","Manufacturer":"CiscoSystems","Product_Categorization_Tier1":"HardwareInfrastructure","Product_Categorization_Tier2":"Network","Product_Categorization_Tier3":"Switch","Company":"4584",},{"CI_Name":"EB2CMA02","Manufacturer":"CiscoSystems","Product_Categorization_Tier1":"HardwareInfrastructure","Product_Categorization_Tier2":"Network","Product_Categorization_Tier3":"Switch","Company":"4584"}]}
```

I need to keep CI_Name in a .TXT file ( `here for e:g EB2CMA01 & EB2CMA02` )and take these name from that .txt file and match that against the dictionary and then export the rest of key:value of that dictionary to excel with respective VALUE under the KEY as row &column.

Comment: I'd read the dictionary into a Pandas Dataframe and then use Pandas to_excel.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your statement. You need a : after the "value" keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas for this , for install pandas just > pip install pandas

```
import pandas as pd

P = {"@odata.context":"https://remedy.data/network","value":[{"CI_Name":"EB2CMA01","Manufacturer":"CiscoSystems","Product_Categorization_Tier1":"HardwareInfrastructure","Product_Categorization_Tier2":"Network","Product_Categorization_Tier3":"Switch","Company":"4584",},{"CI_Name":"EB2CMA02","Manufacturer":"CiscoSystems","Product_Categorization_Tier1":"HardwareInfrastructure","Product_Categorization_Tier2":"Network","Product_Categorization_Tier3":"Switch","Company":"4584"}]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(P['value'])
df.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

Comment: but i have to get the input from .txt where EB2CMA01 and EB2CMA02 is listed

Comment: @Jintu can you add how is your txt?

Comment: my.txt file will have EB2CMA01 and EB2CMA02

Comment: getting this error :

`8 #print response.content
      9 P = response.content
---> 10 df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(P['value'])
     11 df.to_excel('test.xlsx')

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`